# How to optimize a nested objective function with constraints in R

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, mle

I'm trying to implement the following Log-Likelihood function in R.

∑*(i∈I)ln{∑*(s∈S)p(s)* p_i(s)}

variable p_i(s) is given as `(err_mat[i,j]*(1-Beta) + Beta*(1-err_mat[i,j])`
variable p(s) is probability of the process s and there are up to 12 possible processes.

I have written a simple representation of how pi_s is calculated and it depends on an unknown parameter: beta. The input to the optimization function is a matrix of "errors" (either 0 or 1) and estimates which data generating process most likely fits the data. There are 12 possible processes that could have produced the data, giving 12 probabilities p_s, constrained between (0,1) and should sum up to 1 to be estimated. And there is a 13th parameter, beta, which captures the noise in the process.

so far, with lots of search on stackoverflow, I have the function below:

```
  `beta_llh <- function(err_mat) {
    nr <- dim(err_mat)[1]
    nl <- dim(err_mat)[2]
    pi_s = c(rep(1,12))
    function(pars) {
     for (i in 1:nr){
      for (j in 1:nl){
        pi_s[i] = pi_s[i] * (err_mat[i,j]*(1-Beta) + Beta*(1-err_mat[i,j]))
      }

       pi_s[i] = pi_s[i]*p_s[i] # multiply pi_s by p_s
    }

    result = sum(llh) # MAKE a sum for the pi_s and p_s 
  }
 }`
```

Sample error matrix as below:

```
err_matrix = matrix(c(rep(0,40), rep(1,440)), nrow=12, ncol=40, byrow= TRUE)
```

My optimization function currently is:

```
optim(par=c(rep(0,13)), fn=llh_value, lower=c(rep(0,13)),upper=c(rep(1,13)), method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

My questions now are:

1. How do i code the constraint that the first 12 parameters sum up to 1.
2. How do i code the outer summation given that I already have one unknown parameter in the inner summation. When I try to pass the inner summation into an outer for loop using the code below, I get an error.

   ```
   llh_All <- matrix(rep(1,2), nrow=2, ncol=1 )
   for(s in 1:n){
     dataS = subset(testDF, testDF$ID1 == "s")
     # get its error matrix
     err_mat  <- get_err_matrix(dataS)
     # get its llh
     llh_S = beta_llh(err_mat)
     llh_All[s] <- llh_S
     }
   result = sum(llh_All)
   ```

I get the error below:

```
    Error in llh_All[s] = llh_S : 
    incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix
```

I've spent roughly 3 days trying to fix this myself and I'll be grateful for any help. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To get the parameters to sum up to 1, you could do something like `params[12] <- 1 - params[1:11]`. For the problem with `log(sum(llh))`, it means that `sum(llh)` is not positive or that your function is not returning a number ... in fact, I think several of your problems might be stemming from your `beta_llh` function returning a function, not a value. Try doing `return(res)` or `return(sum(llh))`. Then, for the error related to `llh_All[s] = llh_S`, the previous line should be `llh_S = beta_llh(err_mat)(par)` ... but you'd have to figure out what your `par` should be.

Your question is pretty scattered at the moment, to be honest. There are several bugs in your code that your asking for others to debug, rather than a single, targeted programming question. If this doesn't help, you probably need to distill the problem at bit and be more specific.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes the beta_llh function does return a function, that's the function that I want to optimize over the parameters. I'll work on making the question more specific.

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope you will be able to help some more now, thanks.